# How to use normal inside normal

Tags: texturing, uv

So I have looked around some website, there is something interesting. The model is using 2 normals.

[image]

This normal is used to define the wrinkle of the cloth.

Then there is this normal:

[image]

This normal is used to define the bump of the texture in tiny part of the texture. So this normal is used multiple times for each small parts of the texture.

How can I achieve this is blender with PBR model?

Comment: Hello :). So - you want to combine normal maps? Like, use both on the same faces at once?

Comment: Yes, correct, because the problem if I only use 1 normal and it is converted to low res, the small detail of the 2nd normal will be really bad

Comment: Hello, actually no, the link you gave me have not resolve my question. In that link, it is combining 2 different normal map with both of them are the same size and proportion. In my case this is different, because 1 of the normal map is the layout of the object, another one is much smaller chunk piece of the texture. In your link there is no code which do this.

Comment: Hey :). Well, you can just scale the texture using a Mapping node. The principle should be the same. Or perhaps explain better how you're using the smaller texture.