# Combine 2 normal maps (1 for layout and 1 for detail)

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

So my question got closed when it is not even resolved.

here: [How to use normal inside normal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209505/how-to-use-normal-inside-normal)

So I want to combine 2 different normal map with different size.

1. Normal map for the object layout

[image]

this object normal map is in low poly.

Then I want to define the texture normal (like bump, etc) in another normal map:

[image]

The second image is the normal map for each small chunk piece of the texture. For example for every 1cm - 5cm of the texture should follow this normal map. So the 2nd image / the detail normal map should be repeated many times covering the whole texture.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hey :). You can just scale the small texture using a Mapping node. Or perhaps explain better how you're using the texture.

Comment: With normal maps, the size doesn't matter since they reproduce direction vectors and not displacement vectors. The answers to the question that yours was closed as a duplicate of will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix the 2 textures into a *MixRGB* node. Put the *MixRGB* factor at 0.5, and put the *Normal Map* strength at 2. As they are not supposed to have the same scale, they both use the same UV map but the first one will use a *Mapping* scale of 1 while you'll use a bigger scale for the second one (here x 10):

[image]

[image]