# Confused about normal maps and how they relate to mesh when part of a pack

Tags: materials

Im learning blender and have a question about normal maps. I am making a rock and I am following a baking tutorial that creates a normal map from a high poly to use on a low poly. The current high poly rock has a lot of detail

So part of the tutorial says after i create my rock I am to download a material pack from https://ambientcg.com. The packs here contain the color as well as a normal map included. First question is what is the main difference between the normal map i create and the one that is included in the materials? Obviously my normal is related to my mesh but what is the one in the pack related too?

In my case can I use the color from the materials pack and combine it with the normal from my mesh that i created and completely ignore the one in the pack? Or do I use 2 normals if possible?

A bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: it's hard to tell as we don't know what tutorial you are following and what and why they recommend, you can create your own normal map from a high-poly version, you can use an imported one, you can also mix 2 normal maps with a MixRGB: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209518/combine-2-normal-maps-1-for-layout-and-1-for-detail

Comment: generally there is only one normal map though

Comment: OK thanks I think i will try and test the different scenarios and see what works. Thanks for the help

Comment: The way I would see it is that the normal map you create shows the details from your high poly model on your lower poly model. The Normal Map you downloaded shows the "artificial" bumps that are a part of the texture (material) that goes on the object ("Dirt" bumps for a dirt material, for example). In this case, mix the 2 normal maps using a MixRGB (or vector math) node before connecting to the normal input of whatever shader (BSDF) you are using.

Comment: The basic gist is, 1) texture artists and tutorial writers know only a teensy bit more than you do (using normal maps from texture packs is not a good idea, because of the way normal maps work); 2) there aren't any rules, and you can do whatever you want to try that ends up looking good.  I don't recommend using a normal map from a texture pack, but if you want to, the best way to combine would be to put it on your high poly prior to baking, at which point it will be built into the normal bake.